# QMessageBox QTextCursor::setPosition out of range

Tags: python, python-3.4, pyqt5, qmessagebox

If I execute the following code, I get the message:

```
QTextCursor::setPosition: Position '5' out of range
```

This is just a small example to reproduce the error message. Does any one now how to avoid this or why it happen?

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets 
import sys

class programm(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

  def __init__(self):
    QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

  def message(self):
    dialog = QtWidgets.QMessageBox(self)
    dialog.setText('Test')
    dialog.setDetailedText('Test')
    dialog.setVisible(True)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
prog = programm()
prog.show()
prog.message()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Did you use Qt Designer for the original code?

Comment: @ham-sandwich: No, I didn't.

Comment: Does the code otherwise work? You may find this is a problem with your window manager rather than pyqt5.

Comment: Obviously a Qt bug of some kind (there are lots of similar reports if you do a web-search on the error message). I can't reproduce it on Linux using qt 5.3.1 and pyqt 5.3.2. What's your setup?

Comment: I use qt 5.3.1 and pyqt 5.3.1. The message just seems to be a warning, the rest of the code is working fine.

Comment: Have you tried keeping a reference to dialog, e.g. self.dialog = QtW....

Comment: look: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-38178

Comment: It's a Qt's problem, not python's or smth else's. Sometimes Qt screws up :)